# In Objective-C, how to use 'self' in main() function?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, self

I have the definition:

```
@interface MyClass: NSObject
{
   NSString *str;
   id delegate;
}
-(id)initWithStr:(NSString *)str
        delegate:(id)delegate;
@end
```

and when i send message to my object in the main.m like this:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
       [[MyClass alloc] initWithStr:@"abc-xyz"
                           delegate:self];
    }
}
```

There is the error **"Use of undeclared identifier 'self' "**.   I m a newb of objective-c and I know that the 'self' indicates the receiver of the message, but i don't know how to use it in the main() function. Can anybody tell me what's wrong about it and how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happens is that self points to the executing object. main function is not in a class, so, YOU CAN`T call self on a function, only on a method of a class. What are you really trying to do? Use the AppDelegate. When you create a new project, Xcode already gives you some files. One of then is called (YOUR_PROJECT)AppDelegate. This is the starting point of your application.

If you have any customizations to do in the initialization of your app, find your AppDelegate.m file, look for `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` method, and place your code inside this method.

Never mess up with main.m file.

EDIT:

For Mac OS X here's what you should do:

Create a class to act as a delegate and add that class to the delegate.

```
 MyDelegate * d;
 MyClass * c;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {

       d = [[MyDelegate alloc] init];

       c = [[MyClass alloc] initWithStr:@"abc-xyz"
                           delegate:d];
    }
}
```

Then, on MyDelegate, implement the callbacks of the protocol.

If you want to have a callback on main, you will have to use a function pointer. You'll have to enter in the world of plain C. I don't recommend since you want to use object oriented stuff. Don't mix both, or you'll create a monster.

Comment: Thank you very much! But I want to write a 'Command Line Tool' or a daemon application. In these cases there are not "(YOUR_PROJECT)AppDelegate" in the project at all, how can i do?

Comment: It's not possible to do such as a command line tool for iphone. Unless it's jail broken. in any case, App delegate is the start point for it, not main function. Your main function should have something like this:  return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]))

Comment: I see. Thank you! BTW, what's about the Mac OS X?

Comment: You want iPhone or a mac os application? If it's for mac, you can register a function pointer for a callback and in your class, you have to initialize the object with this function pointer. That's plain C.

Answer (score 0):

You do not use the main() function like this.
Do this in the AppDelegate, then it will just work.

Comment: I do not know about that. can you provide some example codes? thank you very much.

Comment: Just start a new project in Xcode. It will already have the AppDelegate set up for you!

Comment: But I want to build a "command line tools" or a daemon tools.

Answer (score -1):

> In Objective-C, how to use 'self' in main() function?

This is impossible.

Because "self" can only be used by instances of objects.
main() is a function. Functions are not objects but code "on its own".